# check an object for a property value java

Tags: java, list, loops

I'm looking for a way to loop through the properties of each object of a list of objects and check if the value of a specific property matches another value I already have. For my case, both values are strings, but I would like to know how to check for any type of value.

Iterating through the list is simple, I am confused how to check the properties though. What would be the best way to do this?

The objects are created through this constructor:

```
public Undroppable(Player nameOfPlayer, ArrayList<ItemStack> items1){
    Player pl = nameOfPlayer;
    ArrayList<ItemStack> storedHits = items1;
};
```

ItemStack is a type that was created in the api I am working with. items1 is an arraylist of itemstacks.
The constructor is used in the class like this:

```
storedDeaths.add(new Undroppable(p, hits));
```

storedDeaths is a list for the objects created. p is a player, another type in the api I'm using. Hits is the arraylist of itemstacks I was talking about.

I can loop throught the list of objects to access an object, but I don't know how to loop through each objects to check the properties.

Comment: Really people? I'm asking a legit question I don't know the answer to, nor could I find an answer to help me ANYWHERE, and your going to vote this down just because your more expirienced than I am and this question is useless to you? Really guys?

Comment: The question is incredibly unclear. Consider editing it without the "noise" and with some simplifed example. Also properties ? Do you mean fields ? You are missusing java terminology.

Comment: What do you mean by noise? I simplified what I'm doing, be thankful I didn't post tons of code like other do. By properties I mean the properties of an object. I don't know what the proper term is in java, but the term in javascript would be a key.

Answer (score 0):

Just access your property in the loop and check if it is equal to what you want to match.

```
List<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<YourObject>();


String stringToMatch = "match"

for(int i; i<list.size(); i++){
 if(list.get(i).getStringProperty().equals(stringToMatch){
    //do something
 }
}
```

Edit:
your class isn't set up correctly.You arent doing anything in the constructor.
Class variables need to be declared as such:

```
public class Undroppable{
 private Player player; //this is important
 private List<ItemStack> items1; //you must declare these

 public Undroppable(Player nameOfPlayer, ArrayList<ItemStack> items1){
  this.player = nameOfPlayer;
  this.items1 = items1;
}

 public Player getPlayer(){ return this.player; } // now you can access this way
 public List<ItemStack> getItems1{return this.items1}
```

Comment: when you say getStringProperty, do you mean get and then the name of the property or is that a method to get a value of a string propertY?

Comment: it is a method to get the value of a string property. You could also get the property directly if it is a public variable, In that case use list.get(i).propertyName

Comment: I don't know how your class is structured, try adding your class structure to your post?

Comment: I added details to the post, can add more if you need. getStringProperty doesn't seem to work. says the method 'getstringproperty is undefined for type object.'

Comment: consider reading the Java tutorials on Objects and Classes to get a proper grasp of the language https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: why do they have to be public? Each argument is already defined in the method where I call the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
interface PropertyProvider<E> {

    public E getValue(); 
    public void setValue(E value);
}

class Container implements PropertyProvider<String> {

    private String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then use this method to check whether one of the properties contained in the ValueProviders matches a value:

```
public static <E> boolean containsNestedProperty(Collection<PropertyProvider<E>> coll, E value) {
    boolean contains = false;

    for (PropertyProvider<E> provider : coll) {
        E item = provider.getValue();

        if (item != null && item.equals(value)) {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return contains;
}
```